# Using Transactions or Locking in Entity Framework to ensure proper operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am fairly new to EF and SQL in general, so I could use some help clarifying this point.

Let's say I have a table "wallet" (and EF code first object Wallet) that has an ID and a balance. I need to do an operation like this:

```
if(wallet.balance > 100){
    doOtherChecksThatTake10Seconds();
    wallet.balance -= 50;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, it checks to see if a condition is valid, then if so it has to do a bunch of other operations first that take a long time (in this exaggerated example we say 10 seconds), then if that passes it subtracts $50 from the wallet and saves the new data.

The issue is, there are other things happening that can change the wallet balance at any time (this is a web application). If this happens:

1. wallet.balance = 110;
2. this operation passes its "if" check because wallet.balance > 110
3. while it's doing the "doOtherChecksThatTake10Seconds()", a user transfers $40 out of their wallet
4. now wallet.balance = 70
5. "doOtherChecksThatTake10Seconds()" finishes, subtracts 50 from wallet.balance, and then saves the context with the new data.

In this case, the check of wallet.balance > 100 is no longer true, but the operation still happened because of the delay. I need to find a way of locking the table and not releasing it until the entire operation is finished, so nothing gets edited during. What is the most effective way to do this?

It should be noted that I have tried putting this operation within a TransactionScope(), I am not sure if that will have the intended effect or not but I did notice it started causing a lot of deadlocks with an entirely different database operation that is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  **Optimistic concurrency** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904

```
//Object Property:
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
//Object Configuration:
Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion().IsConcurrencyToken();
```

This Allows dirty read. BUT when you go to update the record the system checks the rowversion hasn't changed in the mean time,  it fails if someone has changed the record in the meantime.
Rowversion is maintained by DB each time a record changes.

**Out of the box EF optimistic locking.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use Transaction Scope.

Import the namespace

```
using System.Transactions;
```

and use it like below:

```
public string InsertBrand()
        {
            try
            {

                using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
                {

                   //Do your operations here
                    transaction.Complete();
                    return "Mobile Brand Added";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This pattern works, but it best used in different scenarios. especially when combined with MSDTC. eg cross server/cross db challenges. The issue as described is the classic optimistic locking scenario.  When combined with EF you can have performance and isolation level issues.  Just google that and you will see a few forum posts.  I personally wouldnt recommend someone use this approach unnecessarily in EF .

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use one or many internal queues and consume this queue(s) by one thread only (producer-consumer-pattern). I use this approach in a booking system and it works quite well and is very easy.

In my case I have multiple queues (one for each 'product') that are created and deleted dynamically and multiple consumers, where only one consumer can be assigned to one queue. This allows also to handle higher concurrency. In a high-concurrency scenario with houndredthousands of user you could also use separate servers and queues like msmq to handle this.

There might be a problem with this approach in a ticket system where a lot of users want to have a ticket for a concert or in a shopping system, when a new "Harry Potter" is released but I dont have this scenarios.